# Simple Logarithm and JavaScript Question

Tags: logarithms

I have a simple formula that I am trying to convert to JavaScript, I'm just stuck trying to reverse it. My math skills have deteriorated over the last few years and im stuck.

Here is the formula
[image]

And here is my interpretation of it in JavaScript

```
2 * Math.log2(apx) = fval
```

Given that I only know the value of fval, and im actually trying to get the value of apx, can anyone tell me how I would go about doing that?  Double points if you can help with the javascript conversion :)

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE!  You can actually post math formulas here using $\LaTeX$ and MathJax.  A homegrown tutorial is [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference?s=1|1.1819).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main thing to remember about logarithms (indeed, their defining property) is that for positive real numbers $a$ and $b$, with $a\neq 1$, we have
$$\large a^{\log_a(b)}=b$$

Therefore, if you have 
$$2\cdot\log_2(N)=A_N$$
then dividing both sides by $2$ we get
$$\log_2(N)=A_N/2$$
and then raising $2$ to the power of both sides we get
$$N=2^{A_N/2}$$
I don't know whether to expect any floating-point arithmetic problems, but naively turning this formula into Javascript would give

```
apx = Math.pow(2, fval / 2)
```

Comment: Excellent! that did it.  Thank you very much!

Comment: I'm not a photography expert but it looks to me like you've got things backwards in the code you posted: the picture you posted says that $A_N$ is the `aperture value` and $N$ is the `f/number`, so if I've interpreted your variable names correctly, you should want

`2 * Math.log2(fval) = apx`, which would of course make the correct conversion in the other direction just `fval = Math.pow(2, apx / 2)`.

Comment: Yes, I think I had it backwards to start with.  I have a mapping of numbers and equated values to reference my answers with, but there are others I needed to calculate on the fly, hence this question.  Thanks for your help!